# Return DbSet of BaseEntity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is it possible to return `DbSet<BaseEntity>` form a method in Entity Framework using table per concrete type inheritance or other inheritance type?

`Teacher` and `Student` inherited from `Person`.

```
DbSet<Teacher> Teachers;
DbSet<Student> Students;

DbSet<Person> GetGenericDbSet(int entityType)
{
    if (entityType == 0)
    {
        return Teachers;
    }
    else
    {
        return Students;
    }
}
```

Compile error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `DbSet<Teacher>` to `DbSet<Person>`

Comment: As long as your Teacher and Student classes inheritate from Person, this should be possible.

Comment: though, it doesn't look like the "db way" to do. How is your schema defined ?

Comment: What's is exaclty your issue? Is your code compiling? I guess not since you've commented the return statements. In that case, you probably have to cast the result: `return this.Teacher.Cast<Person>();`...

Comment: @fharreau updated question, cast will return IQueryable not DbSet.

Comment: Do you really need a DbSet ? IQueryable offers almost the same features (lazy loading, construct SQL queries, etc).

Comment: Does `Teacher` and `Student` inherit from `Person`?

Comment: @fharreau yes. Teacher and Student inherit from Person

Comment: AFAIK, I am afraid you can't do that out of the box with Entity Framework. May be if you create a `View` or a `SQL Function` and customize the mapping in your EDMX... But I have never done that so I can't help you with. You can also create a change request on the EF github repo and ask them to make the IDbSet<T> covariant, but I guess they can't do that due to internal limitation ...

Comment: @fharreau In `IDbSet<T>` members `T` appears in both input and output positions, so it simply cannot be made variant.

Comment: @mojtaba357 Looking at your recent questions, looks like you are trying to do something terribly wrong. When using any of the EF inheritance strategies, you'd normally have only single `DbSet<Person>` in your `DbContext` and will use it for all operations involving derived types (`Add`, `Remove` etc.), including queries (just eventually applying `OfType` filter if needed). I would suggest you reading [this post series](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph).

Answer (score 1):

Even if `Teacher : Person` and `Student : Person`, you can't return a `DbSet<Teacher>` as a `DbSet<Person>` because `IDbSet<T>` is not [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) (it looks like even if the base interface `IQueryable` is covariant, its child interface does not keep that property).

Another solution would be to change the return type of your method to `IQueryable<Person>` (as `IQueryable<T>` is covariant, it will accept an object with a child class of `T`):

```
IQueryable<Person> GetPerson(int type)
{
    if (type == 0)
    {
        return Teachers.Cast<Person>();
    }
    else
    {
        return Students.Cast<Person>();
    }
}
```

But doing this, you will lose all the Entity Framework Cache capabilities (`Attach`, `Find`, etc)

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[Person]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Person]'.'

DbSet is required not IQueryable. anyway thanks for answer.

Comment: That's what I feared. I removed that part from the answer. There is still the second one for other people who can change the return type.